# Why might a default evaluate before the cases when inputing from a file?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, switch-statement, default

My program is having some hiccups involving my default statement. While
going through the code, my cases seem to be skipped, resulting in output that looks like this instead of just the data from 'Account Number'  down, without the error comments

```
Error! INVALID TRANSACTION CODE!   
Error! INVALID TRANSACTION CODE!    
Error! INVALID TRANSACTION CODE!   
Error! INVALID TRANSACTION CODE!   
Error! INVALID TRANSACTION CODE!   
Error! INVALID TRANSACTION CODE!   
Error! INVALID TRANSACTION CODE!   
Account Number: 467343   
Beginning Balance: $23750.4   
Ending Balance: $2075.4   
Interest Paid: $150   
Amount Deposited: $6000   
Number of Deposits: 3   
Amount Withdrawn: $21825   
Number of Withdrawls: 5
```

The output is fine if I take out my default, but I still need it as a fail safe for if the transaction code is not a valid letter. How can this be fixed without taking out the default?

This is the file and a snippet of the code below.

```
467343 23750.40  
W 250.00  
D 1200  
W 75.00  
I 120.74  
W 2500.00  
W 3000  
D 800  
I 30.88  
W 16000.00  
D 4000.00
```

```
inFile >> transCode >> transAmount;

while (!inFile.eof())
{
    switch (transCode)
    {

    case 'D':
    case 'd':

        acctBalance = endingBalance + transAmount;

        amountDeposited = transAmount + amountDeposited;
        numberOfDeposits++;

        break;

    case 'I':
    case 'i':

        endingBalance = endingBalance + transAmount;

        interestPaid = interestPaid + transAmount;

        break;

    case 'W':
    case 'w':

        endingBalance = endingBalance - transAmount;
        amountWithdrawn = amountWithdrawn + transAmount;

        numberOfWithdrawls++;

        if (endingBalance < minimumBalance && !isServiceChared)
        {

            endingBalance = endingBalance - serviceCharge;

            isServiceChared = true;
         }
        break;

    default:
        cout << "Error! INVALID TRANSACTION CODE!" << endl;
        break;

    }

    inFile >> transCode >> transAmount;
```

Comment: `while (!inFile.eof())` is a code smell - where's the code inputting `transCode`?

Comment: @TonyD I apologize. I have added the input its  inFile >> transCode >> transAmount; it is both before the while loop and after the last bracket.

Comment: @Tony: This is a rare example of `while (!inFile.eof())` being used correctly.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: almost - it will only work correctly if the last line is terminated by some whitespace, which decent editors enforce (in the form of a newline) but can be a nasty thing to debug.  It also fails to check badbit, so parsing may have failed.

Comment: @user3656280 have you tried adding `std::cout << *transcode * << transcode << ", transAmount " << transAmount << '\n';` in the loop?

Comment: @user3656280: you'd be better off using `while (inFile >> transCode >> transAmount)` and ditching the `eof` stuff altogether....  As is, if your input can't be parsed (e.g. say `transAmount` is a numeric type but the input has an illegal character like say "X", you'll never reach eof and will loop forever...

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or this question should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `transCode` is a `char`, so on the first line of the file (`467343 23750.40`) it gets set to `4` then `transAmount` gets set to the rest of the word, `67343`. Then on the next loop `transCode` gets set to the next character, which is the `2` at the start of `23570.40`, and transAmount gets set to `3570.40`

You need to do something like read the first word on the line into a string then, see if it is a valid code or a number. Or you could read `transCode` and check it before reading `transAmount`.

Comment: I'd worked through the same possibility too, but it doesn't explain so many copies of the "default" message.

Comment: @TonyD, won't the stream's `failbit` be set when trying to read `W` as a double, and not update `transCode` after that, so it just loops on the same error? In any case, `inFile >> transCode >> transAmount` is very fragile and can't handle unexpected numbers of fields in a line, or fields in unexpected formats.

Comment: My thinking was that if `transCode` is a `char` and `transAmount` a `double` or `float`, then the first line's broken up as 4 / 67343, then 2 / 3750.40, then the other lines are parsed successfully too... badbit is never set and the eof is reached.  Anyway, your comment about MCVE is on the money.

Comment: @TonyD, you're right ... you thought it through further than me :)